# Third party libraries conflict in my Grails 2.5.5 application

Tags: grails, flying-saucer

I have a problem and my ideas how to solve it has just finished. Maybe you can help me.
In my project I'm using `'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.1.7'` this library used depend on `com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7`. Unfortunately I should import `com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7` too. So I have something like this:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    dependencies {
        build ('com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7') {
            excludes 'bctsp-jdk14'
            excludes 'bcmail-jdk14'
            excludes 'bcprov-jdk14'
        }
        compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.1.6'
     }
}
```

The problem occurs when I'm trying to use flying-saucer library. I've got an exception: `com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[Ijava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)`

The question is how can I fix something like that since both library and I are using only `com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7`

Thanks.

Comment: what Grails version do you use?

Comment: @saw303 2.5.5 and for now I have no opportunity to change it to the newest

Comment: Since both libraries are using the same iText version 2.1.7 there should be no problem at all. What happens when you exclude iText from your dependencies and use the one that is provided by flying-saucer-pdf?

If you want to go further please create a WAR by `grails war` and list all JARs that are located in that WAR under `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @saw303 if I totally removes iText from dependencies flying-saucer starts working but I don't know if something else may stops working :) It's quite big application. WAR contains flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.7.jar and itext-2.1.7.js2.jar but there is no normal itext-2.1.7.jar.

Comment: @saw303 yes... When I removes itext-2.1.7.jar Jasper reports lib stops working. It throws an exception "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)Vjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError"

Comment: alright then, welcome to the jar hell. Since flying-saucer-pdf uses the normal 'itext-2.1.7' (see http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf/9.1.6/flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.6.pom) `itext-2.1.7.js2.jar` must be imported by some other lib or your dependencies. what happens if you replace the `itext-2.1.7.js2.jar` with `itext-2.1.7.jar` and run the war?

Comment: @saw303 unfortunately jasperreports uses itext-2.1.7.js2.jar see [mavenrepo link](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.5.0/jasperreports-5.5.0.pom)

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156884/discussion-between-saw303-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Grails project of yours is suffering in the so called [JAR Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell). Your Grails app dependencies and the transitive dependencies (the ones your dependencies & Grails plugins use) are creating a conflict. In your case multiple versions of a class on your classpath.

All you can do is to analyze your WARs classpath and try identify the conflicting classes and their JARs.

After that try one of the following resolutions:

- find a common version of iText that works for your Grails app and its plugins
- fork the conflicting Grails plugin and try to clean up the dependencies of that plugin. Then use the fork.

While searching for some other solutions I have found a promising software project called [jHades](http://jhades.github.io/). Maybe you might want to take a look at this one too.

jHades allows you to analyze your WAR file by simply execute the following command

```
java -jar jhades-standalone-report.jar path/to/war/webapp.war
```

Additionally you can troubleshoot your web application by adding jHades to your classpath (as a dependency) and add a [jHades servlet listener](http://jhades.github.io/documentation.html#troubleshooting) to your web.xml.

```
<listener>
        <listener-class> org.jhades.JHadesServletListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```